# How to avoid the impact of kernel threads and timers on the process？

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

The operating system runs multiple processes at the same time, and events such as peripheral interrupts, clock interrupts, and process scheduling will occur during the process of running.

The Linux operating system can use "isocpus" to isolate the CPU to ensure that the isolated CPU is not freely scheduled. But the kernel thread and timer cannot be restricted. How can we restrict the impact of the kernel thread and timer on the process?

Even modify the kernel.

Thank you.

Comment: If you overclock the core by 1% you will have made up for all overhead.  What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: Just to explore the possibility of linux tailoring.

Comment: So just set smp_affinity to 0 for all interrupts and see what happens. No interrupts = no scheduling.